# c# paragraph delimiter in text read from keyboard

Tags: c#, text, analysis, delimiter, paragraph

How is it possible to let user enter more paragraphs before enter or carriage return is supplied?

Knowing that after each paragraph one should hit enter to mark that he finished that paragraph.

I have to count this paragraphs. In the case that the text is read from a file, maybe that would be ok (I still don't know for sure what delimiting character I am looking for for counting paragraphs).

But when you read text inputs by a user from the keyboard, how can I count paragraphs - no idea.

Let's say user starts and input some statements and then hits enter... program finished... 1 paragraph and that's it.

How can I allow the user to input 2 paragraphs or more and count them?

I'd probably prefer simple "beginner" method instead of regex... I can count sentences but not under any way paragraphs inputs from keyboard... probably wants to be a loop or something to allow user to input more then one paragraphs and than what user does when he finished inputs of paragraphs? hits enter again... so confusion, confusion, confusion..

Comment: Use RichTextBox or TextBox with MultiLine set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line = Console.ReadLine();
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    lines.Add(line);
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then `lines` will contain all of the paragraphs that the user entered, and they can indicate the end of their entry by hitting Enter without entering anything.

EDIT: If you only need to count how many paragraphs the user entered (not store them), then this would work:

```
int paragraphsEntered = 0;
string line = Console.ReadLine();
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    paragraphsEntered++
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} paragraph(s).", paragraphsEntered);
```

Comment: hmm probably like I want to count the lines, as the lines would be the paragraphs so split by "/n" - it might work, I will try this with text read from a file.
But I have no idea how to constantly allow user to input more paragraphs before hitting enter.
Idea is probably a while loop but no idea to implement.

Comment: As if user enters a sentence, another sentence and then hits enter. Then with this done I have 2 sentences and 1 paragraph. But I have no idea how to let user enter more than 1 paragraph without hitting enter between them and only hit enter when he/she finished entering (as I know paragraphs would be delimited by the "enter" key).

Comment: Perhaps my post wasn't clear enough, but the idea above is that the user would hit Enter after each paragraph, and then hit Enter one extra time at the end to indicate that they are done. Does that not make sense?

Comment: Hmm I don't know if I will be allowed to use this "List" class as I did not officially learn it yet. The idea with a do while loop, enter after each paragraph and two enters at the end of input will be ok to use for me so thanks for that. It was simple but it was just not coming to mind.

Comment: In fact I think the thing I found not to be ok is the requirement which says: that program has to allow more paragraphs to be entered before one time final "enter" key stroke. -> Than would it result I'd have to split the paragraphs by something else than "enter"? And than what would that be? :-))
As I know paragraphs, normally in something like MS Word are delimited by "enter" key.

Comment: It's somewhat ambiguous, but it could be describing exactly what I've been describing - there is one (extra) final Enter key stroke to indicate the end of the input.  What are the specific instructions about how to take in the paragraphs that are entered?

Comment: Lol nope. Nothing. It just has to accept multiple paragraphs.
I cannot get the concept of making the program allow the user to "enter more paragraphs before the enter key is supplied" - in quotes I've put one and the final requirement of a bigger program which I could have the option to not implement but it is just my ambition to see if this requirement sounds right or is a bit ambiguous as to "allow someone to enter more than one paragraph in the console before finally pressing, at the end of his/her paragraphs, the "enter" key.

Comment: If no other idea or "enter more paragraphs before the enter key is supplied" in fact sounds impossible than I will have to "modify" the requirements as to make the user enter each paragraph with "enter" at the end.
And at the end of the whole input of text I will have the user to show the program that's the end of input by hitting the "enter" key 2 times.

Comment: I think I decided: it definitely has to be like that paragraph enter paragraph enter paragraph enter enter and if string is null or empty when user pressed enter, than that's the end.
Do while string is not null or empty, {count paragraphs}; when string is empty, that's the end. (I am not allowed to use List of strings). I will probably have to count paragraphs in a similar way I've been counting sentences with a foreach loop checking for each char in text if it's a '\n' (I hope '\n' is what I will be looking for counting paragraphs).

Comment: do { userText = Console.ReadLine(); } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userText))

Comment: I am like a fresh woman starting to drive, I cannot even get the code in here to look nice and coloured on that grey background and formated properly :-)) - hence new on the forum (my first day.. night.. whatever it is).
Thanks folks! I am probably half sorted now but I got to go to sleep cause tomorrow I got to still go to my 9 to 5 job which at the moment is not programming as probably everyone can see, am just in the first college year :-)).

Comment: Added a suggestion that should work if you just want to count the paragraphs and not store them.  Also made the original code more concise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms you can use TextBox with Multiline set to true.  Please check [TextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) documentation with example on how to do it or you can use [RichTextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)

In order to count paragraphs you can use following code:

```
var paragraphs = myTextBoxControl.Text.Split('\n').Count;
```

Comment: Thanks. So I'll count paragraphs by '\n' - I need to use simple beginner method anyway so I'll do a foreach and looking at each character, then when I find '\n' will count as paragraph.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, just counting '\n'

If you need to iterate each paragraph you can to this way:
`foreach (var paragraph in myText.Split('\n'))
{
    numberOfParagraphs++;
   // do some work with paragraph
}`